# Hosting multiple S3 origins under one CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to host multiple S3 origins under the same CloudFront distribution? Let's say I have bucket A and bucket B which both host static websites--could I add them both as origins to a distribution, and specify a path e.g. `/alternate` for the origin from bucket B so that visiting `http://<distribution>/` took you to the website hosted by bucket A and visiting `http://<distribution>/alternate` brought you to the one hosted by bucket B? From what I've read so far it seems possible to have multiple origins, not necessarily multiple S3 origins.

Comment: You want 1 Distribution connected to 2 different S3 buckets? Thats not possible. It is always a 1:1 relationship. Why don't you want to create 2 Distributions and set the same cname?

Comment: @MarcJohnson that isn't correct.  You can connect up to 25 origins (S3 or not) to single distribution, based on default limits.

Comment: @danielle yes, you can... after declaring the additional origin in the Origins tab, Path Behaviors map path patterns (e.g. `/alternate*`) to a specific origin... but the catch is that by default, the *entire* path sent by the browser is the what is sent to the bucket (including the leading `/alternate`).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot True! Sorry, my fault. You can find information about limits here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot does that mean I would need an additional directory with that name in my bucket? I don't have an origin path specified, just an additional cache behavior with the path pattern `/alternate*`

Comment: Origin Path empty means a request for `/alternate/thing` goes to the origin as `/alternate/thing`.  Origin Path `/some` means a request for `/alternate/thing` goes to the origin as `/some/alternate/thing`.  There isn't a way to remove anything from the request path unless you use Lambda@Edge to modify the request... so, yes.  The Path Pattern does not change what the origin actually sees.

Comment: Is there a way to treat the domain as part of the path, for example `/foo.com` would go to the foo bucket and default(*) would go to another bucket.  What about stashing a variable in the header somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple S3 origins to a CloudFront distribution

However, behaviors are locked to a specific origin. Behavior controls the path. So, if /static is used by Origin A/S3 A, you can't have /static go to /Origin B/S3 B

Someone suggested using multiple CloudFronts with the same CNAME. That does not work either. CloudFront will not allow the same CNAME to be used in multiple distributions.

Academically speaking, this may be possible through LambdaEdge or some other external process that is checking S3 A, and if it is unavailable (say - under maintenance while  new code being pushed), it can go and update CF Behavior for /static to Origin B/S3 B.

I wish AWS came up with a more elegant solution to this use case. Like allowing same CNAME in multiple distributions, or providing some kind of R53 integration with S3 buckets (never tried putting two different S3 buckets behind R53 .. probably will not work because the host header would change)

Answer (score 3):

You can attach a Lambda function as a trigger to intercept CloudFront's routing. The implementation is quite *involved*; but would permit your specific use case.

**Example Implementation**:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/

**Lambda@Edge**:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)