# Multiple S3 Buckets Under a Single Cloudfront Distribution (Uploads via Carrierwave)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

This existing question seems to be the closest to my question:

[Hosting multiple S3 origins under one CloudFront distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446228/hosting-multiple-s3-origins-under-one-cloudfront-distribution)

I have a multi-tenant Rails application. My intent is to have some static content (logos etc.), variable content (user avatar uploads etc.) and then tenant specific content (document uploads).

From what I understand I could do the following:

- Create a 'static' bucket for general site content
- Create a 'user' bucket for users files
- When tenants are created create a bucket for uploads etc
- Add all the buckets origins to the single Cloudfront distribution

When the files are uploaded / accessed the bucket would be specified so that all the files are segregated.  I am planning to used signed URLs - wanted to mention that in case it matters.

My file uploads are managed via the Rails Carrierwave gem.  It looks to me that I can set my static bucket as default then specify the alternate bucket as needed and AWS takes care of the rest.

My question: Am I correct in my logic / understanding here of the AWS Cloudfront / Origin system.